# Laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException and Logout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm having the weirdest bug ever and have no idea where to start debugging. I have a form that I use to send the client some email. This form is submitted via ajax to the server and a response is sent back.

```
$.post('{{ route('some.route') }}', $('#check-form').serialize(), function (data) {
                buildNotification('Success', "Sent email, 'success');

                doAction('reset', true);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                buildNotification('Error!!!', err.message !== undefined ? err.message : "Failed sending email", 'danger');

                doAction('reset', true);
            });
```

I also have set the `{{ csrf_field() }}` in my form and if I check in Chrome Dev Tools in the networking tab I can see that the `_token' field is set.

The thing is when I submit the request the response from the server is the HTML for a `TokenMismatchException`. I disabled token verification for the specified route and I STILL GET A `TokenMismatchException`..

And after this if I refresh the page I'm redirected to the login page again(so the sessions gets destroyed somehow I guess). I searched everything I could find but nothing seems to apply to my case.

Some other thing I noticed is that I only get this behavior when running on Chrome(Chromium in my case). Also tried Incognito Mode because I thought that some extension might cause the bug but no, still the same problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Laravel configures any ajax calls using Axios. Taken from bootstrap.js.

```
/**
 * Register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

However as you are using JQuery, you will need to make sure that you have configured your ajax setup so that it can pass crsf field as follow.

```
// main.blade.php
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


// boostrap.js, after you have imported jquery

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Hopefully that should do the trick.

Comment: While this is a valid point, OP has already mentioned that they're including the token in the form data payload.

Comment: Yes. CSRF Token is already being sent in the form field via a hidden `input` with name `_token`.. I think it might be a Chormium bug because everything seems to be working just fine in Chrome or Firefox :/